# No hardware virtualization but how to install haxm?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, virtualization, haxm

For installing android studio haxm I see there is a need of hardware visualization but my computer does not support hardware virtualization. Do I have any way to install haxm or any alternative platform to code for android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer doesn't support hardware virtualization, you won't be able install `HAXM`, but it doesn't mean that you won't able to run Android emulator.

Notice that:

> Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) is a hardware-assisted virtualization engine (hypervisor) that uses Intel Virtualization Technology (Intel® VT) to speed up Android* app emulation on a host machine. In combination with Android x86 emulator images provided by Intel and the official Android SDK Manager, Intel HAXM allows for faster Android emulation on Intel VT enabled systems.
>
> From: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Just install Android Studio and when you would create emulator, be sure that it is ARM based, not `x86` or similar. Your emulator would load and runs slower, but it would work good enough.

You would also able to run Genymotion Android emulator, but it would be able to emulate only one processor of your virtual device.

Hope it help